# How to extract text that lies between parentheses

Tags: c#, regex

I have string like **(CAT,A)(DOG,C)(MOUSE,D)**

i want to get the DOG value **C** using Regular expression.

i tried following

```
Match match = Regex.Match(rspData, @"\(DOG,*?\)");
if (match.Success)
 Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

But not working could any one help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Maybe `(?<=\(DOG,)\w+(?=\))`? See https://regex101.com/r/WgaXFi/1. Or `(?<=\(DOG,)[^()]*(?=\))`

Comment: FYI, you were missing a `.` before `*?` (I think?). But of course, if you're only interested in what comes after the comma, go with Wiktor's suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<=\(DOG,)\w+(?=\))?
(?<=\(DOG,)[^()]*(?=\))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WgaXFi/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<=\(DOG,)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `(DOG,` string
- `\w+` - one or more letters, digits, connector punctuation
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `(?=\))` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with `)`.

Comment: @GabrielStancu I am only answering the current question, and the problem statement sounds as "*i want to get the **DOG** value `C` using Regular expression.*"

Comment: It worked for me, actually DOG, CAT are Key's. it will be dynamic so thanks

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can also use a capture group:

```
\(DOG,([^()]*)\)
```

**Explanation**

- `\(DOG,` Match `(DOG,`
- `([^()]*)` Capture group 1, match 0+ chars other than `(` or `)`
- `\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xqLLxg/1) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/ZlJA7Q)

```
String rspData = "(CAT,A)(DOG,C)(MOUSE,D)";
Match match = Regex.Match(rspData, @"\(DOG,([^()]*)\)");
if (match.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Output

```
 C
```